# MVC Decimal MySql issue

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm not sure why number 9000.00 stored in MySql as Decimal(12,2) is displaying 9 millions in views
1.00 displays 100 (1,00 is correct)
5.77 displays 577 (5,77 is correct)

[Value retrieved from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqpx.png)

I tried

```
DisplayFor(m => m.MyNumber)
Model.MyNumber.toString("n2")
Model.MyNumber.toString("C")
```

MySql

```
Decimal(12,2)
Default collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
Default chartset utf8mb4
```

Comment: Looks like not-a-dot decimal part separator on the client side + retrieve number as string issue.

Comment: 993777M is retrieved from database and it is passed to the view with automapper, 9937.77 is stored in mysql, I use entity framework

Comment: Is the value also passed as decimal (9937.77) in the view model?

Answer (score 1):

First check if the value is correctly retrieved from the database and how it is passed to the view.

Comment: 993777M is retrieved from database and it is passed to the view with automapper
9937.77 is stored
I have a build in production thats works perfectly, my current build has this issue